# Spring Integration microservices visualization tool

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, visualization, microservices

I have an application based on microservices which communicate to each other via queues and topics. Each microservice is built using Spring Integration *with XML configurations*.

Is there a tool/framework that I could use to automatically generate diagram for the whole application, which would ideally show Spring Integration details for each microservice and as well the connection (via queues/topics) between the microservices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each application can be visualized using the [spring integration runtime graph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#integration-graph) together with a viewer application.

See the [file-split-ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp) for an example. The viewer mentioned on the README page is in the the angular 1.x branch of the referenced spring-flo project.

Also see [Tim Ysewyn's blog post here](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/architecture/2018/01/27/Visualizing-your-Spring-Integration-components-and-flows.html) "VISUALIZING YOUR SPRING INTEGRATION COMPONENTS & FLOWS".

If you create your microservices using Spring Cloud Stream and deploy/orchestrate them using Spring Cloud Dataflow, you can visualize them at a higher level; examples are in the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_creating_fan_in_fan_out_streams).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, before posting this I googled most of those links, but I really hoped there's a viewer enable to visualize across multiple applications.